# How should Viennese coffee be taken?

Tags: coffee, serving

Is there a proper way Viennese coffee should be taken? What is the little spoon for?  When/how should the sparkling lime water be taken? etc.

A video would be helpful.

Was just introduced to the a Viennese coffee shop, and there was some confusion between the people explaining this.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your picture, you're asking about Weiner Melange coffee in Vienna, a serving of half espresso coffee and half milk foam.  That's instead of American "Viennese Coffee", made with whip cream and cinnamon.  Assuming that's correct:

- The spoon is intended for mixing the milk foam and coffee.  You may wish to add sugar as well.
- The sparkling water is a chaser to clear your palate.

The above is based on personal tourist experience and some internet research.  Some links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Melange
- http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-wiener-melange.htm
- http://www.tasteofaustria.org/coffee/

Comment: Actually, I told it was a Kapuziner, rather than Wiener Melange ... but the references you gave explain a lot.  And thank you again.

Comment: Does the cup sit on the saucer off centre or does it look like that due to perspective? A slightly larger saucer with off-centre cup would be perfect to hold a few biscuits.

Comment: @jude - I am going to have to go back and find out.  What I can tell you - for sure, is that handle is crafted for Right-Handed people, so ... I never really started thinking that far ahead!   Will let you know.

Comment: I've seen off-center saucers in upscale cafes.  It's a thing.